# Python string parse error

Tags: python, string

This is my test code, `test.py`:

```
str = input("IP: ")                                               
print(str)
```

When running I get this error:

```
➜  PingScript git:(master) ✗ python test.py                      
IP: 1.1.1.1 


Traceback (most recent call last):                      
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>                            
    str = input("IP: ")                                          
  File "<string>", line 1                                         
    1.1.1.1                                                      
        ^                                                 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This happens only if I use `1.1.1.1` as input and not if I use `1.1` as input, what is happening here? I've tried to parse it with `str(str)` but I still get the same error.

Comment: Don't name a variable `str`. What do you expect `str(str)` to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`input()` tries to parse the input as a python expression. Use `raw_input()` instead.

It works with `1.1` as input because that's a literal float value, a number, in python.

It could be that you are following a tutorial meant for Python 3, but are using Python 2 instead. In Python 3, the `raw_input()` function was renamed to `input()` and the old `input()` function was removed altogether. If so, please install Python 3 and continue from there.

Comment: He's using parenthesis for `print`. Do you think perhaps he's targeting Python 3 but using Python 2?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Excellent point, and I think you are right. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

`input()` evaluates what you enter as if it were valid Python code. `raw_input()`, accepts the input and returns it as a string. Since `1.1.1.1` is not valid Python code, you get the error. `1.1` is a float in Python, which is why it seems to work:

```
>>> input('Enter: ')
Enter: 1+1
2
>>> raw_input('Enter: ')
Enter: 1+1
'1+1'
>>> input('Enter: ')
Enter: 1.1
1.1000000000000001
```

Answer (score 0):

str() is an inbuilt function in Python language which converts other data types to a string. So str must be a keyword, which cannot be used as a variable name. Kindly use any other variable name instead of "str".